# Capturing a two-way relationship in mysql

Tags: database-design

i have two tables:
1) Users
2) Scenarios

Relation between them can be described as:

User can have 0 or more Scenarios
Scenario must be associated with exactly one User

One way is to create User_Scenario_rels and use ID from users and scenarios table to create relationships. But is this the best practice?  Is this 1 to many relationship?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a "one to many" relationship - one scenary has one user, one user has many scenarios.

It's commonly modeled by a "user_id" column on the scenario table.

In terms of database design as practised in the field, there's no distinction between "a user has 0 or more scenarios" and "a user has 1 or more scenarios"; in theory, if you wanted to impose the rule that all users MUST have at least 1 scenario, you would implement a constraint.

Comment: is there a difference between 0 or more and 1 or more?

Answer (score 0):

> One way is to create User_Scenario_rels and use ID from users and
>   scenarios table to create relationships. But is this the best
>   practice? Is this 1 to many relationship?

Whether it fits your requirements and implements a 1:n relationship depends on whether you get the keys and constraints right. It's not the only way, and in this particular case, it allows a scenario to exist without a user.

```
create table users (
  user_id integer primary key
);

create table scenarios (
  scenario_id integer primary key
);

-- Separate table allows users to have zero scenarios.
create table user_scenarios (
  user_id integer not null references users (user_id),
  scenario_id integer not null references scenarios (scenario_id),
  -- This primary key lets each user have multiple scenarios
  primary key (user_id, scenario_id),
  -- This unique constraint allows each scenario id number to 
  -- be used only once. (So it's associated with only one user.)
  unique (scenario_id)
);
```

It's better (and easier) to include a non-nullable user_id column in the table of scenarios, as Neville K said.